# android.app.AppOpsManager not find in android project

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm developing an Android application with Android Studio. I have added the package Google Maps for including the maps in my project. I have done everything to do this,create the key and the signature in the developer console,add the key in the manifest and the "google-play-services" package through gradle. But,when I launch the app,I have this error:

```
Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.hg.a
```

Why? I haven't found any fix for this issue on web.However,the app works and shows the map inside my activity.

Comment: This is perfectly normal behavior. Apps often have references to classes that do not exist in the virtual machine, such as when an app tries referencing a class that was added in a recent version of Android. So long as the app does not execute any lines of code that actually try using the class, everything is fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok,so I have to worry about this or not? Can I keep on safely?

Comment: You do not need to worry about it.

Comment: due to this map activity on my phone is not working :( @CommonsWare please help